# Canvas not clearing after redraw

Tags: html, canvas, dart

I made an animation in Dart using Canvas. A circle travels diagonally at 50 px/s across the screen. However, the canvas won't clear when the clearRect method is called. Can any one tell why?

[I looked at another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716083/why-wont-my-canvas-clear-between-animation-frames) but that didn't help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ForceTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="forcetest.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <canvas id="stage" width=500 height=500></canvas>

    <script type="application/dart" src="forcetest.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

forcetest.dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart';


List<ICanvasObject> objects = new List<ICanvasObject>();
CanvasElement canvas = querySelector('#stage');
CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

void main() {
  objects.add(new Particle(100.0, 100.0));

  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);

}

class Particle implements ICanvasObject, IPhysicsObject {

  double _sx;
  double _sy;
  Vector2 _s;
  double _vx = 0.0;
  Vector2 _v = new Vector2(50.0, 50.0);

  Particle(double x, double y) {
    _sx = x;
    _sy = y;
    _s = new Vector2(x, y);
  }

  void draw(CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx) {
    ctx.arc(_s.x, _s.y, 10, 0, 2*PI);
    ctx.fill();
  }

  void recalculate() {
    _s.addScaled(_v, 1/60);
  }

}

abstract class ICanvasObject {
  void draw(CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx);
}

abstract class IPhysicsObject {
  void recalculate();
}

void update(num time) {

  for (IPhysicsObject object in objects.where((i) => 
        i is IPhysicsObject
      ).toList()) object.recalculate();


  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  for (ICanvasObject object in objects) object.draw(ctx);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `beginPath()` inside your method:

```
void draw(CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();  // reset path
    ctx.arc(_s.x, _s.y, 10, 0, 2*PI);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

If you don't the current path will accumulate all those arcs and when calling `fill()` the new together with all the old ones will be filled making it look like the canvas isn't cleared.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. I thought I was forgetting something.